# java input validation: how can I split the user input at the space?

Tags: java, input

My assignment:

> Perform input validation by making sure that the user enters a positive integer number for feet, a nonnegative decimal number for inches, and a positive decimal number for weight. See the sample session for details. In particular, note the format for the echo-printed height and weight values and for the generated body-mass-index value.

My program works, but I can't figure out how to make it look like the sample program below. I have to have the user input the height in feet then space then inches. I don't know how to split the user input at the space.

Sample session:

```
Enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): hi there
Invalid feet value. Must be an integer.
Invalid inches value. Must be a decimal number.
Re-enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): 0 9
Invalid feet value. Must be positive.
Re-enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): 5.25 0
Invalid feet value. Must be an integer.
Re-enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): 5 9.25
Enter weight in pounds: 0
Invalid pounds value. Must be positive.
Re-enter weight in pounds: 150.5
height = 5'-9.25"
weight = 150.5 pounds
body mass index = 22.1
```

My code so far:

```
package ch14;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputString;
    double bmi;
    double pounds;
    double inches;
    String feet;

    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): ");
    inputString = stdIn.nextLine();


    try
    {
        Double.parseDouble(inputString);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        System.out.println ("Invalid inch value. Number must be a decimal.");
        System.out.print ("Re-enter height in inches: ");
        inputString = stdIn.nextLine ();
    }

    inches=Double.parseDouble(inputString);

    if(inches<=0)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid inch value. Must be a positive number.");
        System.out.print("Re-enter height in inches:");
        inputString = stdIn.nextLine();
        inches=Double.parseDouble(inputString);
    }

    System.out.print("enter weight(in pounds) ");
    inputString = stdIn.nextLine();

    try
    {
        Double.parseDouble(inputString);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid pound value. Number must be a decimal.");
        System.out.print("Re-enter the weight in pounds: ");
        inputString = stdIn.nextLine();
    }

    pounds=Double.parseDouble(inputString);

    if(pounds <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid pound value. Must be a positive number.");
        System.out.print("Re-enter the weight in pounds:");
        inputString = stdIn.nextLine();
        pounds=Double.parseDouble(inputString);
    }

    System.out.println("Height = " + inches + "\"");
    System.out.println("Weight = " + pounds + " pounds");
    System.out.printf("Body Mass Index = %.1f\n",(pounds * 703.)/(inches * inches));

    }//end main
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You split using [.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) so, for a single space...

```
mystring.split("\\s");
```

for any number of spaces...

```
mystring.split("\\s+");
```

Both of these operations return an array of Strings which can then be accessed like any other array for example...

```
String mystring = "Hello World";
String[] words = mystring.split("\\s");
System.out.println(words[0]); //<--- Would print "Hello"
```

For your particular problem you're probably going to want to convert these String objects to Double's or something. You can do this using `Double.parseDouble()`. For example,

```
Double number = Double.parseDouble("1.0");
```

This above line of code converts the `"1.0"` String object into a double of value `1.0`.